# Limsup of a sequence of random variables, equivalences

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_i$'s are i.i.d, with the density distribution $f(x) = e^{-x}$, $x \geq 0$. I want to show that
$$P(\limsup \frac{X_n}{\log{n}} =1)=1$$ 
However, I don't know very well how to work with that set. Thinking in the definition of limit superior, I see that

$$\left\{ \limsup \frac{X_n}{\log{n}} = 1 \right\} = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \geq N} \left\{ |sup_{m \geq n}( \frac{X_m}{\log{m}})-1| \leq \frac{1}{k} \right\} =$$ $$=\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \geq N} \bigcap_{m \geq n} \left\{  \frac{X_m}{\log{m}}-1 \leq \frac{1}{k} \right\}$$

Which it doesn't seems very friendly to me. Isn't this set related in any way with the definition of limit superior for a sequence sets? In that case, I could solve the problem easily using Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: You could show that $\Bbb P(\limsup_n\{X_n/\log n>1+\epsilon\})=0$ but $\Bbb P(\limsup_n\{X_n/\log n>1-\epsilon\})=1$, for all $\epsilon\in(0,1)$.